# VirtualHost error. Apache fails with this configuration

Tags: dns, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, linode

I am trying to setup a Linode VPS. VirtualHost configuration is as follows:

```
# domain: regenucell.com
# public: /var/www/html/regenucell.com/public_html/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@regenucell.com
  ServerName  regenucell.com
  ServerAlias regenucell.com  www.regenucell.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/regenucell.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/regenucell.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/regenucell.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I do `sudo a2ensite regenucell.com.conf` and `sudo systemctl reload apache2` , I get the following error 
**Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

What am I missing here? I spent the whole night trying to figure out what I missed and yet I am nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. It was because log folder and log files did not exist. After I created log folder and inside files (log/error.log and log/access.log) error was gone.